# How to tell Java compiler to not complain about certain exceptions not being caught or thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Is there a way to tell the Java compiler to not complain about a certain exception not being caught or thrown if I am 100% sure that the exception will never occur?

Comment: You mean a checked exception?

Comment: it's just looking out for you man =/

Comment: Nothing like making a smart ass comment on SO, then months later googling a question and finding the result tagged with my own smart ass comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean checked exceptions, you can't. Typically I would catch the exception, but propagate it into a `RuntimeException`, e.g.

```
try {
   // Do something which could, but won't, throw SomeCheckedException
} catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
   throw new WorldHasGoneMadException(e);
}
```

You may very well want to create a *specific* exception for exactly this kind of scenario - while I wouldn't suggest `WorldHasGoneMadException` for the real name, something similar would be appropriate. This isn't just "something unexpected has happened" but "wow, I would have bet good money that this *really, really* couldn't happen".

Oh, and of course your unit tests *won't* cover this case. Live with it :)

Comment: Actually, I like the name "WorldHasGoneMadException". Thanks for answering.

Comment: This is a nice approach, particularly because it converts the exception to the right level of abstraction. [This article by Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html) has some interesting thoughts about checked versus unchecked exceptions. The only quibble might be that in _Effective Java_, Josh Block has the guideline "Use checked exceptions for recoverable conditions" and it's hard to see how to recover from the condition that the world has gone mad. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757058/348975) is really good, but I would `assert` that there is already such a `WorldHasGoneMadException` class and thus no need for you to create a specific exception for it.

```
try {
   // Do something which could, but won't, throw SomeCheckedException
} catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
   assert false : e ;
}
```

Run testing with assertions enabled.  If you get some AssertionErrors you know there is some problem with your assumptions.  During production, violations of your assumption (you did thoroughly test it so there will be no violations, right?) will be silently swallowed.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a setting, which I am pretty sure there is not, I would not recommend using it.

I usually run across those "will never happen" events while debugging a production error where it "happened". ;-) At the very least I would suggest a try/catch with some ERROR level logging in it so that at least you are made aware of the problem on the odd case when it does actually happen.

Hope this helps.